# Unable to install Plugman in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli, plugman

I want to install Plugman in iOS for managing the Phonegap plugins. I am using the below command in Terminal.

npm install -g plugman

**But I am getting the below error,**

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/gtmac/.npm/npm/1.3.4/package/package.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/gtmac/.npm/npm/1.3.4/package/package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/gtmac/.npm/npm/1.3.4/package/package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'plugman' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "plugman"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/gtmac/Documents/Sinu/Insightix
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /Users/gtmac/.npm/npm/1.3.4/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open '/Users/gtmac/.npm/npm/1.3.4/package/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gtmac/Documents/Sinu/Insightix/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by running the command after executing 'sudo -s'

1. $ sudo -s
2. $ npm install -g plugman

Comment: still unable to install. Plz help

Comment: getting this error
> code Z_BUF_ERROR
> npm ERR! errno -5
> npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /Users/habibali/.npm/_logs/2018-12-10T11_42_50_023Z-debug.log